# Selecting higher values from arrays that are not far from each other

Tags: clustering

I have arrays $a_1...a_n$ each containing $m$ values inside. I want to select one value from each array. Let us say the selected values from each array are represented with $x_1...x_n$ and the distance amongst every selected pair of values as $d_{ij}$ (distance is simply how far the indices in the arrays are for every pair), where $1 \leq i \leq n$ and $1 \leq j \leq n$. The group of values selected should have the maximum value of $\sum_{k=1}^n x_k - \sum d_{ij}$ from all possible such sets. What technique can I use to solve this problem? Thanks.

I give an example here.

The arrays:

```
a1 = [1 2 10 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
a2 = [3 2 2 2 8 1 3 4 5 12 1]
```

The values selected are $x_1 = 10$ and $x_2 = 8$ because they are close to eachother and note that we didn't select 12 from the second array. I hope this makes it clear.